# Remove duplicates from a CSV file based on two columns

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting, duplicates

I have a CSV (in `$inputCsv`) with three columns from which I would like to remove duplicates from SubName while keeping the minimum Rank category (minimum = TEST1 and maximum = TEST3)

```
Name     SubName     Rank
-----    --------    -----
NAME1    SUBNAME1    TEST1
NAME2    SUBNAME2    TEST1
NAME2    SUBNAME2    TEST3
NAME3    SUBNAME3    TEST2
NAME4    SUBNAME4    TEST3
NAME4    SUBNAME4    TEST2
```

Desired result:

```
Name     SubName     Rank
-----    --------    -----
NAME1    SUBNAME1    TEST1
NAME2    SUBNAME2    TEST1
NAME3    SUBNAME3    TEST2
NAME4    SUBNAME4    TEST2
```

Of course TEST3 can be kept in case it is the only value available.

For ease, I transform `Rank` into a numeral column so that I can order it. I tried several `Sort-Object` assemblies without success with, for example:

```bash
$inputCsv | Select-Object "Name", "SubName", "Rank", @{Name = 'Weight'; Expression = { 
    if ( $_."Rank" -eq "TEST1" ) { 1 } 
    elseif ( $_."Rank" -eq "TEST2" ) { 2 } 
    elseif ( $_."Rank" -eq "TEST3" ) { 3 } }
} | Sort-Object "SubName",{$_.Weight -lt 3} -Unique
```

Comment: Use Group-Object and then Select first item of each group.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have an example?

Comment: Could RANK have 2 or more numeric digits?

Comment: No, only 3 values ​​are possible in Rank: TEST1, TEST2 and TEST3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` first grouping by the `SubName` property then for each group use `Sort-Object` sorting by `Rank` (the expression `$_.Rank -replace '\D' -as [int]` is removing any non-numeric digit and then converting the resulting string into an integer for proper sorting) lastly use `Select-Object` to take only 1 object and skip the rest:

```bash
$inputCsv | Group-Object SubName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group |
        Sort-Object { $_.Rank -replace '\D' -as [int] } |
        Select-Object -First 1
}
```

**NOTE:** If the values in the `Rank` property will always be a single digit you could just use `Sort-Object Rank`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$csv = @"
Name,SubName,Rank
NAME1,SUBNAME1,TEST1
NAME2,SUBNAME2,TEST1
NAME2,SUBNAME2,TEST3
NAME3,SUBNAME3,TEST2
NAME4,SUBNAME4,TEST3
NAME4,SUBNAME4,TEST2
"@
$table = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv

$filtered = $table | sort-Object -Property Name,Sbuname,Rank | Group-Object -Property Name, SubName | Foreach { $_.Group[0]}

$filtered
```

Results

```
Name  SubName  Rank
----  -------  ----
NAME1 SUBNAME1 TEST1
NAME2 SUBNAME2 TEST1
NAME3 SUBNAME3 TEST2
NAME4 SUBNAME4 TEST2
```